# How to see backlink history

Tags: seo, google-search-console, backlinks

Is there a way to see a graphical representation of a website's backlink history?

I have tried Magestic SEO, but the data looks inaccurate:

[image]

Does Google Webmaster Tools come with such a data visualisation tool?

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, Google Webmaster Tools doesn't show this kind of history chart.

However, many services online show backlinks history like [Ahrefs.com](http://ahrefs.com). This is my favourite because there is many useful charts visible for free. Moreover, free version can be enough to analyze backlinks of a website. Then, you can pay to see more data.

Answer (score 0):

Keep in mind that the Majestic graph you are looking at says that it is non-cumulative.  According to them you were getting a couple links per day for a long while and then suddenly got a bunch all at once.  Check to see if they have a cumulative view that would slope up more gradually.

Google Webmaster Tools does not show you history of your inbound links over time.

[Seomoz's Open Site Explorer](http://www.seomoz.org/) (Free 30 day trial and then $99/month) claims as a feature: Historical Link Analysis -- A historical view of your competitive domain metrics over time